# Using two 404 page not found pages for different language versions of a site

Tags: .htaccess, error-handling, http-status-code-404

Is it possible to use two **404 page not found** pages for different language versions of a site?

**mydomain.cz** points to the root of **mydomain.com** with both using the same 404 error page. Is it possible, using .htaccess, to direct users encountering an error on the .cz domain to be shown another 404 to the .com users?

At the moment for 404 errors in .htaccess we have:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /projecterror.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible through Apache, but I would recommend directing to a .php page that displays dynamic content based on information parsed from

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']